# having vive 1.0 and 2.0 audio mirroring problems

Tags: audio, htc-vive

I have both the vive 1.0 and 2.0 (full system).  In SteamVR, I set the main audio to the HTC HMD and the mirroring audio to the computer so that I can hear it in the head set and through the computer.

When I set it this way, sometimes it performs as expected (audio in both HMD and computer).  Other times, it audio is only in the HMD.  To fix this:
- Set SteamVR main audio to the computer speakers and mirror audio to 'No mirror'
- Close SteamVR app
- Open SteamVR app
- Set SteamVR main audio to the expected correct setting - main audio to HMD and mirror to the computer speakers
- Close SteamVR
- Open SteamVR and audio is now in both HMD and computer speakers
This solution works 90+% of the time, but I would like to find a more direct solution than this work around.

This problem occurs on both 1.0 and 2.0 (full system) on multiple hardware platforms (laptops and desktops computers from different makers).

thanks